# Missing premise in uniqueness portion of theorem

Tags: functions, solution-verification

Problem statement, as written:

Let $f\colon A \rightarrow C$ and $g\colon A \rightarrow B$ be functions. Prove that there exists a function $h\colon B \rightarrow C$ such that $f = h \circ g$ if and only if $\forall x,y \in A$, $g(x) = g(y) \rightarrow f(x) = f(y)$. Prove that $h$ is unique.

The problem is... as written, $h$ isn’t unique. The only way I’ve been able to reconcile this theorem is by adding the premise, “let $g$ be surjective.” Can anyone confirm this? The following problem in the exercise set is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3670815/another-existence-and-uniqueness-proof-critique-involving-composition-of-functio?noredirect=1#comment7543639_3670815), and, as you can see, includes the phrase “suppose $g$ is bijective” in an analogous place to where “suppose $g$ is surjecrive” would make this problem work. Perhaps a typo or omission?

I can provide a link to my proof upon request- it just seems when my posts get too long you guys run away

Comment: Wait!  I don't understand your objection... the problem *does* includes the phrase "suppose $g$ is bijective" and *YOU* are the one who left it off!  As bijective includes being surjective and injective that *WAS* part of the original problem.  So by leaving it off, the resulting error and falseness is *entirely* on you!

Comment: @fleablood, no, that’s a link to the next problem in the problem set. The problem statement for this exercise appears, as written, at the top of the post.

Answer (score 1):

If $y \in B$ is not in the range of $g$,
it obviously doesn't matter what you take for $h(y)$. 
So, assuming of course $C$ is not a singleton, what you need for $h$ to be unique is that $g$ is surjective.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, as $f$ is fixed initially, I suppose it is not, in general, guaranteed to be a singleton.